# Configuring Azure's Event Hub to receive events from ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-eventhub

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to configure network settings within event hub so i can successfully send data via the ASP.NET MVC application while running locally (localhost) as well as when I deploy the application in azure's dev/qa/production web environment.

I have build a proof of concept console application in .NET locally and on Azure's EventHub side added my IP address within Networking/Firewall settings, and have no issue sending data and receiving data from a local machine.

But when I try the same code in the ASP.NET MVC web application, the page just hangs on `CreateBatchAsync()` method and does not return any exception..

```
var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName);

EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Event 1z at " + DateTime.Now.ToString())));
           
await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The call to `CreateBatchAsync` is the first point in your code to request a network operation and, consequently, will trigger creation of the connection and link to the Event Hubs service.  The connection attempt has a timeout associated with it which is 60 seconds in the default configuration that you're using.  Depending on the error that it is encountering, you may see retries take place, each of which would have a 60 second timeout.  With the default configuration, this would look like a 3 minute hang.  (60 seconds * 3 attempts)

The most common connection issue in an enterprise environment is that the ports needed for AMQP over TCP (5671/5672) are not open.  Changing the transport to AMQP over WebSockets often helps, as it will use port 443 and may be routed through a proxy, if needed.

For more information, you may want to look at the sample for [configuring Event Hubs clients](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md#configuration) and the [Event Hubs network troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/troubleshooting-guide).

Comment: Thanks for your information, very informative. But still no luck, i have no problems sending data within a test console app. It's when i try to run the same script from MVC application, locally while using localhost - it is just hanging on producerClient.CreateBatchAsync(); line.  I am pretty sure port 443 is open and i used AmqpWebSockets transpot type.

Comment: Seems like we may want to start peeking under the covers; I'd recommend capturing the ETW logs emitted by the SDK using the `AzureEventSourceListener`.  [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Diagnostics.md#logging).   The following event ids would be the most interesting:  3-5, 55-67,

Comment: Thanks Jesse, i will give it a try. Just out of curiosity - is it even possible to call Event Hub as a Producer while running the code in a web environment locally, while pointing to your local host ? I just spoke to my network admin and he mentioned that in order for this to work i would have to somehow keep ports open with some third party open

Comment: So long as you're able to make an outgoing network call over TCP or WebSockets, there shouldn't be an issue publishing events.   That said, I'm not overly familiar with the web host that you're using nor machine configuration;  it's possible that there's some sandbox in place that's blocking you.   The point of failure certainly appears related to establishing a connection.

Comment: The issue was resolved - Thanks for your feedback Jesse

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out.  If you don't mind sharing, I'm curious as to the root cause.

Comment: Absolutely, I was trying to call Async Task method which contained Event Hub client from a synchronized MVC controller method. Found a work around it initially which allowed me to access it  - but it just hanged on on  the  producerClient.CreateBatchAsync(); line. So at first i thought this was related to a port. To resolve this i had to convert a controller method to a Async Task Method. Thanks again.